# Logo of Java application changes after launch

Tags: macos, dock, java

I have a Java application in my dock, whose icon appears as the following when it is unopened:

[image: unopened SQL developer]

However, after opening the application, the icon changes into the Java coffee cup logo:

[image: opened SQL developer]

This makes it hard to distinguish from other running Java apps, which all happen to do the same thing.

Is there any way to prevent this icon change?  I'm running 10.8.4.

Comment: I suspect it depends on what the app does - does the original exec another app and then exit?